# Error in Xcode 12.2: Provisioning profile doesn't include the push notifications entitlement

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, provisioning-profile, apple-developer

I am new to Xcode and I'm trying to build an archive to upload to the App Store Connect, but I am getting the following error:

```
Provisioning profile <my_profile_name> doesn't include the Push Notifications entitlement.
```

My app has the push notification feature and I'm using Firebase  Cloud Messaging to deliver those notifications.

What I have tried so far:

- Check the "Automatically manage signing", but Xcode fails to
  provision the target.
- Delete the provisioning profiles in ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles and let Xcode regenerate them, but the error persists.
- Create my own Provisioning Profile on
  https://developer.apple.com/. It has the push Notifications enabled
  capability, but the downloaded version of it doesn't have the
  entitlement.
- Add, delete and add again the push notifications
  capability in the "Signing and Capabilities" tab on XCode.
- Edit the entitlements file, and have created new Provisioning Profiles without any success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finnally, I have solved this error!

The problem was in the entitlements files on my project: they were generated with two entries:

1. Push Notifications with the boolean value 1;
2. aps-environment with the string value 'production'.

The right entry for the Apple Push Notifications service is only the aps-environment, so I just deleted the Push Notifications entry and now I am able to build the archive!

Thank you all for helping me!

Comment: I am grateful for people like you.

Comment: where can I find in flutter project

Comment: @barduchi any screenshots where to find these values?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following:

- Select your app target in project targets.
- Click on the signing & Capabilities tab.
- Click + Capability and add the push notifications capability.

Comment: Hello @rockdaswift, and thank you for your reply!

I already have added, deleted and added the push notifications capability again, in the Signing & Capabilities tab, and the error persists...

Comment: Can you try adding and removing the iCloud capability? it should regenerate the provisioning profiles.

Comment: I tried right now, but without success. I already tried to delete the provisioning profiles to see if the XCode generates them with the entitlement, but nothing worked.

Comment: Do you have the Provisioning Profile Signing Build Settings set to automatic?

Comment: Well, I did what you have asked with the Provisioning Profile Signing Build Settings set to automatic, but then I get the "Automatic signing failed" error on top of the original error :(

Comment: Do you have the correct Team selected in the Signing & Capabilities tab?

Comment: Yes @rockdaswift, I think I have the correct team here.
As I'm trying to create a release version with archive, I have my iOS distribution team selected in the Signing & Capabilities tab, on Release.

Comment: Have you tried to delete the provisioning profiles in ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles? Xcode should regenerate them.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that too... The Xcode regenerates them, but the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem as well. Spoke with someone at apple and they said a few other people had complained as well.

If I validate the app, it fails Mac App Store validation, saying application- name entitlement error. If I validate for external distribution and notarization, it works fine.

In the same week I've updated 3 other mac app store apps with all the same signing certificates, and everything works.

The app I'm having a persistant problem with was open when I upgraded to 12.1.lastX, and then to 12.2. My bad... that was where things got mucked up.

I've tried every suggestion I can find, to no avail. Will probably rebuild from the ground up, or just wait for an update to Xcode.

It's Apple that created the problem, not me. Sometimes they ruin things.